# no viable conversion from 'w9::Product *' to 'w9::List<w9::Product>'

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

This is my code for merging the description and price from two different files and store it in 'priceList'. My problem is, whenever I make an object of 'product', it gives me error of `no viable conversion from 'w9::Product *' to 'w9::List<w9::Product>`.

I tried  to do `std::unique_ptr<w9::Product> product (new w9::Product(desc[i].desc, price[j].price));`

but it won't me add the product to priceList as it says `no viable overloaded +=`

```
w9::List<w9::Product> merge(const w9::List<w9::Description>& desc,
        const w9::List<w9::Price>& price) {
    w9::List<w9::Product> priceList;
    for(int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < price.size(); j++) {
            if(price[j].code == desc[i].code) {
                w9::List<w9::Product> product = new w9::Product(desc[i].desc,
                    price[j].price);
                priceList += product;
            }
        }
    }
    return priceList;
}
```

The output should be like this :

```
Code Description
  4662    tomatoes
  4039   cucumbers
  4056    brocolli
  4067      lemons
  4068     oranges


  Code   Price
  4067    0.99
  4068    0.67
  4039    1.99
  4056    2.49


  Description   Price
    cucumbers    1.99
     brocolli    2.49
       lemons    0.99
      oranges    0.67
```

Also, List is a class template so I assumed that typename T is std::unique_ptr and I am not allowed to change the codes from my header files which inludes the List and Product, Description and Price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up your types:

```
w9::List<w9::Product> product = new w9::Product(desc[i].desc, price[j].price);
```

The right-hand side is a `w9::Product*`, so you have to assign it to a pointer:

```
w9::Product* product = new w9::Product(desc[i].desc, price[j].price);
```

But you say you need a `unique_ptr`, so really:

```
std::unique_ptr<w9::Product> product(new w9::Product(desc[i].desc, price[j].price));
productList += std::move(product);
```

Or just avoid the temporary:

```
productList += std::unique_ptr<w9::Product>(
                       new w9::Product(desc[i].desc, price[j].price));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried using w9::Product at the beginning and realized the huge difference of not using '*'. Also, I tried both but when I used the unique_ptr, it does not let me add product to my priceList. But the first one works. TY

Answer (score 0):

C++ isn't C# or Java: you create objects without `new`. For example:

```
w9::Product product(desc[i].desc, price[j].price);
priceList += product;
```

(I don't know how `w9::List` works; `std::list<w9::Product>` would use `push_back()` instead of `+=` to append an object).